# Is it possible to prevent store admins from ordering products that are out of stock?

Tags: admin, orders

Even with System > Config > Inventory > Backorders set to *No Backorders*, it seems to allow admins to place orders for items that are out of stock, but it gives an error message in red.

I think in general it probably makes sense to allow admins to override the stock level and place the order, so I can see why it's working like this.

But I'm wondering if there's a config option to enforce the *No Backorders* rule for admins as well.  It seems like there isn't based on this check for `$quoteItem->getQuote()->getIsSuperMode()`
https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Observer.php#L302

Comment: This is unfortunate. My client's catalog consists of unique products that should always have a quantity of either 1 or 0. When they don't notice the "This product is out of stock" message while adding items in a created order, they yell at me because stock on certain items goes negative. =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Session_Quote::getQuote()` forces the quote to be in super mode so I don't see any chance to change this behaviour without overriding that function.

Comment: Thanks Alessandro!  Just wanted to make sure I wasn't crazy before I went in and overrode that!